# Stuck at 33% complete when patching client?

Tags: league-of-legends

Anyone ever gets stuck  at 33 percent when your patching your LoL client? Hopefully I'm not the only one. How do I get this fixed? I tried to close it but then it stays at 33% for hours.

Comment: Try unchecking the "peer to peer" box in the settings.

Comment: Repairing usually fixes it.

Comment: Also changing the download to Peer to Peer Transfer sometimes works for some it doesn't. It's in the settings of the client.

Answer (score 1):

My friend has this problem, he tried many things and nothing would work. In the end, he had to go to the windows control panel and uninstall the program, than re download a clean version of the game. However, one thing you should try before going through this is go to `C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\system` and check on `system.config`.

The file should have this text:

> DownloadURL=l3cdn.riotgames.com
>   DownloadPath=/releases/live
>   Region=NA

Than check `user.cfg` and you should find:

> pandoRemoveState = launchedUninstall